# Remove .php extension from the middle of a URL when not using queries

Tags: .htaccess

I can remove the file extension if I am using queries using the below modrewrite code.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

However I am using explode and array shift in PHP to extract the values from the URL. For example one of my urls is as follows:

http://somedomain.com/register.php/attending/email@email.com

Can someone please help me to create the correct rewrite rule so I can remove .php in the middle of the URL.

I tried a few online tools but they only work if I am using queries i.e. ?key=value

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case, the best is to add a rule (before others):

```
RewriteRule ^register(/.+)$ register.php$1 [NC,L]
```